# How to make different versions of a document

Tags: versions

P.S.
If my title looks confusing I would appreciate if someone can phrase it better.

I am in the process of making around 3 manuals that have the same introduction, and the first few sections. background etc. but in section 4,5,6, they are different. Rather than making 3 separate latex documents, I would like to be able to specify in the beginning of the document, which versions of section 4, 5,6 I need to compile this time and ignore the rest.

So my docs have 4 sections,
ABCD
where D could be D1,D2,D3,...

Ideally, at the beginning of the Latex doc, I like to specify which version of document I like to make.

Comment: Is there a reason not to make one core document, and separate files which you include with, well, \include and then filter using includeonly?

Comment: hmm, I don't know \include, only \includegraphics. I will look it up and see if this suit my needs. Thanks

Comment: You can use `\include` for whole chapters and `\input` for any smaller document fragment (e.g. `\input{mysectionD3`}).